# How to increase the size of mtd?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am trying to mount a jffs2 file to /mnt/mtdblock0 but I keep getting errors because mtd is too small.

The commands I run to mount it are:

```
modprobe mtdblock
modprobe mtdram total_size=49152 erase_size=128
dd if=rootfs.jffs2 of=/dev/mtdblock0
mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock0 /mnt/mtd
```

The output for the dd command is:

```
dd: writing to ‘/dev/mtdblock0’: No space left on device
98305+0 records in
98304+0 records out
50331648 bytes (50 MB) copied, 0.295263 s, 170 MB/s
```

After I mount I do "df -h" and get:

```
/dev/mtdblock0 48M 48M 0 100% /mnt/mtd
```

From "mtdinfo /dev/mtd0":

```
mtd0
Name:                           mtdram test device
Type:                           ram
Eraseblock size:                262144 bytes, 256.0 KiB
Amount of eraseblocks:          192 (50331648 bytes, 48.0 MiB)
Minimum input/output unit size: 1 byte
Sub-page size:                  1 byte
Character device major/minor:   90:0
Bad blocks are allowed:         false
Device is writable:             true
```

The size of rootfs.jffs2 is 51280296 and the above command showed that only 50331648 is available, so it makes sense why it is running out of room. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to increase the size of mtd0.

I've been reading articles like [this](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/BootTimeConfigurationOfMTDPartitions) that talk about setting mtdparts, but I don't really understand the process they talk about. I've tried using flash_eraseall, increasing the total_size and erase_size parameters, setting mtdparts from the command line, and setting mtdparts from /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35/drivers/mtd/Kconfig.

Does anyone know what I can do to increase the size of mtd? Any suggestions or resources would be very appreciated. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find work around. I'll post it here in case someone else has this problem.

I started running the commands in [this article](http://daemons.net/linux/storage/mtd.html) and I noticed that "modprobe nandsim" resulted in /mnt/mtd showing a larger size when I did "df -h". When I tried mounting again it appeared to work. "df -h" still shows /mnt/mtd as 100% full, but it is at 50M which is about the size of rootfs.jffs2. And when I look at the mounted file system, everything is where I expect it to be and there aren't any missing/incomplete directories like there were before.

I can't say I fully understand why this fixed it, but it did. If someone else has more insight into why this works, please comment or make it a new answer and I'll mark it as accepted.